# How to rank results in an HTML form using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a simple form in HTML. There are 3 sections (Section A, B and C). As the user fills out the form each section is calculated by displaying total points and percentage. I would like to rank the scores and display it in the ranking column but cannot seem to figure how to do it. For example if Section A has 4 points and Section B has 3 points and Section C has 0 points then section A would have the rank of 1, section B would have the rank of 2 and section C would have the rank of 3. Also having the ranking change as the form is being filled out would be ideal.

I am new to JavaScript and am having trouble on how to logically implement this. This is just a sample of my form. I really have a much larger form with more sections and questions. Please run my code so you can see a better visual. Any code snippets and advice that would help me will be appreciated.

I've tried using if statements in JavaScript but like I said I can't wrap my mind around how to logically do it.

```js
function calcA1R() {
  var Aa1 = document.getElementById('Aa1');
  var Ab1 = document.getElementById('Ab1');
  var Ac1 = document.getElementById('Ac1');

  var Aa1Val = Aa1.options[Aa1.selectedIndex].value;
  var Ab1Val = Ab1.options[Ab1.selectedIndex].value;
  var Ac1Val = Ac1.options[Ac1.selectedIndex].value;

  // returning the sum of the values
  return [parseInt(Aa1Val), parseInt(Ab1Val), parseInt(Ac1Val)].reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0)
}

function calcA1() {
  displaySumA()
}

function displaySumA() {
  document.getElementById('totalA').textContent = calcSumA()
  document.getElementById('TotalASummary').textContent = calcSumA()
  document.getElementById('TotalAPercent').textContent = Math.ceil(calcSumA() / 4 * 100) +'%'
}

function calcSumA() {
  return calcA1R()
}

function calcB1R() {
  var Ba1 = document.getElementById('Ba1');
  var Bb1 = document.getElementById('Bb1');
  var Bc1 = document.getElementById('Bc1');

  var Ba1Val = Ba1.options[Ba1.selectedIndex].value;
  var Bb1Val = Bb1.options[Bb1.selectedIndex].value;
  var Bc1Val = Bc1.options[Bc1.selectedIndex].value;

  // returning the sum of the values
  return [parseInt(Ba1Val), parseInt(Bb1Val), parseInt(Bc1Val)].reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0)
}

function calcB1() {
  displaySumB()
}

function displaySumB() {
  document.getElementById('totalB').textContent = calcSumB()
  document.getElementById('TotalBSummary').textContent = calcSumB()
  document.getElementById('TotalBPercent').textContent = Math.ceil(calcSumB() / 4 * 100) +'%'
}

function calcSumB() {
  return calcB1R()
}

function calcC1R() {
  var Ba1 = document.getElementById('Ca1');
  var Bb1 = document.getElementById('Cb1');
  var Bc1 = document.getElementById('Cc1');

  var Ca1Val = Ca1.options[Ca1.selectedIndex].value;
  var Cb1Val = Cb1.options[Cb1.selectedIndex].value;
  var Cc1Val = Cc1.options[Cc1.selectedIndex].value;

  // returning the sum of the values
  return [parseInt(Ca1Val), parseInt(Cb1Val), parseInt(Cc1Val)].reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0)
}

function calcC1() {
  displaySumC()
}

function displaySumC() {
  document.getElementById('totalC').textContent = calcSumC()
  document.getElementById('TotalCSummary').textContent = calcSumC()
  document.getElementById('TotalCPercent').textContent = Math.ceil(calcSumC() / 4 * 100) +'%'
}

function calcSumC() {
  return calcC1R()
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
     <th>Category |</th>
     <th>Points Possible |</th>
     <th>Points Awarded |</th>
     <th>Percent Achieved |</th>
     <th>Ranking</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td align="center">A</td>
     <td align="center">4</td>
     <td align="center"><b><div><span id="TotalASummary"></span></div></b></td>
     <td align="center"><b><div><span id="TotalAPercent"></span></div></b></td>
     <td bgcolor="#92d050" align="center"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td align="center">B</td>
     <td align="center">4</td>
     <td align="center"><b><div><span id="TotalBSummary"></span></div></td>
     <td align="center"><b><div><span id="TotalBPercent"></span></div></td>
     <td bgcolor="#92d050" align="center"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td align="center">C</td>
     <td align="center">4</td>
     <td align="center"><b><div><span id="TotalCSummary"></span></div></td>
     <td align="center"><b><div><span id="TotalCPercent"></span></div></td>
     <td bgcolor="#92d050" align="center"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Section A.</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>A.1</b></td>
    <td><b>Value</b></td>
    <td><b>Awarded</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a)</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center"><select class="select" onChange="calcA1();" id="Aa1">
                      <option value="0">0</option>
                      <option value="1">1</option>
                    </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b)</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center"><select class="select" onChange="calcA1();" id="Ab1">
                       <option value="0">0</option>
                       <option value="1">1</option>
                       </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c)</td>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td align="center"><select class="select" onChange="calcA1();" id="Ac1">
                       <option value="0">0</option>
                       <option value="2">2</option>
                       </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="subtotal">Section A. Total</td>
    <td align="center"><b>2</b></td>
    <td align="center"><b><div><span id="totalA"></span></div></b></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Section B.</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>B.1</b></td>
    <td><b>Value</b></td>
    <td><b>Awarded</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a)</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center"><select class="select" onChange="calcB1();" id="Ba1">
                      <option value="0">0</option>
                      <option value="1">1</option>
                    </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b)</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center"><select class="select" onChange="calcB1();" id="Bb1">
                       <option value="0">0</option>
                       <option value="1">1</option>
                       </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c)</td>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td align="center"><select class="select" onChange="calcB1();" id="Bc1">
                       <option value="0">0</option>
                       <option value="2">2</option>
                       </select></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="subtotal">Section B. Total</td>
    <td align="center"><b>2</b></td>
    <td align="center"><b><div><span id="totalB"></span></div></b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Section C.</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>C.1</b></td>
    <td><b>Value</b></td>
    <td><b>Awarded</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a)</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center"><select class="select" onChange="calcC1();" id="Ca1">
                      <option value="0">0</option>
                      <option value="1">1</option>
                    </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b)</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center"><select class="select" onChange="calcC1();" id="Cb1">
                       <option value="0">0</option>
                       <option value="1">1</option>
                       </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c)</td>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td align="center"><select class="select" onChange="calcC1();" id="Cc1">
                       <option value="0">0</option>
                       <option value="2">2</option>
                       </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="subtotal">Section C. Total</td>
    <td align="center"><b>2</b></td>
    <td align="center"><b><div><span id="totalC"></span></div></b></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: While this can be done in vanilla js/html, you'd likely have a much easier time doing this using something like React, since it has state management built in and can re-render when state changes.

Comment: That being said, you can give the 5th td element in each tuple in the rankings table an ID, use getElementById() to find the element, and then update the rankings that way.

Comment: to be fair @katamaster818 what he has currently isn't far off from what he wants just waiting for my edit to be approved, as I added his code into a snippet.

Comment: @nicholaslabrecque Yeah, I saw he wasn't far off, I was suggesting this moreso because he said the form in reality will be much larger with more questions - the approach right now isn't super scalable and will have a lot of code duplication

Comment: what are the call chains though my dude you have functions that just call another function to call another function??

Comment: Yeah @katamaster818 He really needs to either clean up what he has and make it a bit more efficient or use angular to do these complex state managements. all depends on what his requirements are i suppose.

Comment: What's the question? It already seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go took a second to clean up some of your code. I added the Ranking function that's probably not the best way to do it but it works. Also I removed the duplicate code and set it into one function that handles all the scoring for each section.

```js
var sections = {
  section_a: 0,
  section_b: 0,
  section_c: 0
}

function calcSection(section) {
  let sum = 0;
  document.querySelectorAll('select.'+section)
  .forEach((input)=>{
    sum += parseInt(input.options[input.selectedIndex].value);
  });
  sections[section] = sum;
  document.getElementById('total_'+section).textContent = sum;
  document.getElementById('summary_'+section).textContent = sum
  document.getElementById('percent_'+section).textContent = Math.ceil(sum / 4 * 100) +'%';
  calcRanks();
}

function calcRanks() {
  let sectionsArr = [];
  let keys = Object.keys(sections);
  keys.forEach((key, i)=>{
    sectionsArr.push({ section: key, value: sections[key], rank: 0 });
    if(i + 1 === keys.length) {
      sectionsArr.sort((a,b)=>{return a.value > b.value ? -1 : a.value < b.value ? 1 : 0});
      let lastIndex = 0;
      for(let i = 1; i < sectionsArr.length; i++){
        let section = sectionsArr[i];
        let lastSection = sectionsArr[lastIndex];
        //console.log(lastSection.value, section.value);
        if(lastSection.value > section.value) {
          sectionsArr[i].rank = lastSection.rank + 1;
        }
        if(lastSection.value === section.value) {
          sectionsArr[i].rank = lastSection.rank;
        }
        lastIndex = i;
      }
      displayRanks(sectionsArr);
    }
  });
}

function displayRanks(sections) {
  sections.forEach((section)=>{
    document.getElementById('rank_'+section.section).textContent = section.rank +1;
  });
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
     <th>Category |</th>
     <th>Points Possible |</th>
     <th>Points Awarded |</th>
     <th>Percent Achieved |</th>
     <th>Ranking</th>
   </tr>
   <tr class="section_a">
     <td align="center">A</td>
     <td align="center">4</td>
     <td align="center"><b><div><span id="summary_section_a"></span></div></b></td>
     <td align="center"><b><div><span id="percent_section_a"></span></div></b></td>
     <td bgcolor="#92d050" align="center" id="rank_section_a"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td align="center">B</td>
     <td align="center">4</td>
     <td align="center"><b><div><span id="summary_section_b"></span></div></td>
     <td align="center"><b><div><span id="percent_section_b"></span></div></td>
     <td bgcolor="#92d050" align="center" id="rank_section_b"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td align="center">C</td>
     <td align="center">4</td>
     <td align="center"><b><div><span id="summary_section_c"></span></div></td>
     <td align="center"><b><div><span id="percent_section_c"></span></div></td>
     <td bgcolor="#92d050" align="center" id="rank_section_c"></td>
   </tr>
</table>



<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Section A.</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>A.1</b></td>
    <td><b>Value</b></td>
    <td><b>Awarded</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a)</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center"><select class="select section_a" onChange="calcSection('section_a')">
                      <option value="0">0</option>
                      <option value="1">1</option>
                    </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b)</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center"><select class="select section_a" onChange="calcSection('section_a')">
                       <option value="0">0</option>
                       <option value="1">1</option>
                       </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c)</td>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td align="center"><select class="select section_a" onChange="calcSection('section_a')">
                       <option value="0">0</option>
                       <option value="2">2</option>
                       </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="subtotal">Section A. Total</td>
    <td align="center"><b>2</b></td>
    <td align="center"><b><div><span id="total_section_a"></span></div></b></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Section B.</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>B.1</b></td>
    <td><b>Value</b></td>
    <td><b>Awarded</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a)</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center"><select class="select section_b" onChange="calcSection('section_b')">
                      <option value="0">0</option>
                      <option value="1">1</option>
                    </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b)</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center"><select class="select section_b" onChange="calcSection('section_b')">
                       <option value="0">0</option>
                       <option value="1">1</option>
                       </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c)</td>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td align="center"><select class="select section_b" onChange="calcSection('section_b')">
                       <option value="0">0</option>
                       <option value="2">2</option>
                       </select></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="subtotal">Section B. Total</td>
    <td align="center"><b>2</b></td>
    <td align="center"><b><div><span id="total_section_b"></span></div></b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Section C.</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>C.1</b></td>
    <td><b>Value</b></td>
    <td><b>Awarded</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a)</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center"><select class="select section_c" onChange="calcSection('section_c')">
                      <option value="0">0</option>
                      <option value="1">1</option>
                    </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b)</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center"><select class="select section_c" onChange="calcSection('section_c')">
                       <option value="0">0</option>
                       <option value="1">1</option>
                       </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c)</td>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td align="center"><select class="select section_c" onChange="calcSection('section_c')">
                       <option value="0">0</option>
                       <option value="2">2</option>
                       </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="subtotal">Section C. Total</td>
    <td align="center"><b>2</b></td>
    <td align="center"><b><div><span id="total_section_c"></span></div></b></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```